# Laravel Socialite login with facebook throws error like: Undefined property: Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteManager::$container

Tags: laravel

laravel 5.8
socialite 4.3

services.php

```
'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_ID_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/login/facebook/callback',
    ]
```

```
Route::get('login/{services}', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider')->name('loginwith');
Route::get('login/{services}/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

Comment: this needs a LOT more content. Use sentences please.

Answer (score 0):

This error was introduced in socialite 4.4.0 and fixed in 4.4.1 make sure your composer didn't inadvertently upgrade to 4.4.0